# Below scenario doesnt work after update from 1.2 to 1.4 version of karate

Tags: syntax, upgrade

I define data in following way

- def inputs = db.readRows(read('../sql/npi_num.txt'))

In my scenario outline under examples for data I provide inputs as below. we use a sql query to read data in to inputs and use it below which was working fine till I updated to 1.4 .
Examples:
| inputs |

I try to Parameterize inputs in different way .It always says inputs in not defined. What would be workable solution here

Comment: I get this error in 1.4.0/1.4.1 but works perfectly fine is 1n 1.2.0                                    
 dynamic expression evaluation failed: inputs